# Not able to git pull/push/clone

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit with Pageant. Most of the time I am not able to pull/push or even clone a new repository. It creates a new git-am process every time I try to pull, which I can't kill, and when try to force kill it through process explorer, it freezes the whole system.

I have tried replacing my putty keys, but nothing seems to work.

OS: Windows 7
TortoiseGit 2.3.0.0

Comment: Try to clone any other repository, for example from GitHub without key

Comment: I removed and updated my putty keys and now it is working fine.